# Can comments in Approvals be merged with List Comments column?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, approval, comments

I have a list in SP2013 with an attached workflow that includes approvals.  In each of the approvals, when the user gets to approve or decline the task assigned to them, there is a section for comments.  These comments are visible in the "Workflow Tasks" list, of course.
I'm looking for a way to merge the comments that the approver puts in the item that is in the Workflow Tasks list, and put them in the comments section of the main list (which has versioning and appending comments activated).  How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I understand that you want to merge "Consolidated Comments" field and "Comments" field in the approval task form.
[image]

Go to SharePoint Designer -> Workflows -> Click approval workflow -> Edit task forms.
[image]

Comment: I can't find anything called "consolidated comments".  I can only see the comments in the workflow task list items, and the comments in the main list.  What I want to do is move the comments from the workflow tasks into the main list item.